# ¿Cómo instalar librerías en Racket?

Tags: librería, instalacion

[Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) es un lenguaje no muy conocido (o eso creo) y por eso la información que puede ofrecer la comunidad es escasa. Sin embargo, Racket tiene en su página oficial una [documentación](https://docs.racket-lang.org/index.html) bastante extensa pero que yo no consigo entender en su mayoría.

Estoy intentando instalar [glfw3](https://docs.racket-lang.org/glfw3/index.html) y [vulkan](https://docs.racket-lang.org/vulkan/index.html). DrRacket (el IDE de Racket) proporciona un package manager que permite realizar la instalación de dichas librerías, con la excepción de que sigue siendo necesario instalar los dll respectivos y el SDK de vulkan. Según [la guía de instalación de Vulkan en Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/vulkan/Setup.html#%28part._.For_.Most_.Users%29) es necesario usar `get-lib-search-dirs` para asegurar que se encuentra el archivo vulkan1.dll.
Lo que no se es dónde debo poner las librerías o carpetas, indicar si Racket debe buscar en algún sitio las librerías, etc.

**TL;DR**

En resumen, ¿cómo se deben instalar las librerías para poder usarlas en Racket? ¿Y en concreto glfw3 y Vulkan en Racket?

Answer (score 0):

según la documentación https://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/config-file.html tenes que buscar en

```
(require setup/dirs)
(find-config-dir)
; en mi caso #<path:/etc/racket>
```

modifica el archivo "config.rktd"

```
#hash(
      (doc-dir . "/usr/share/doc/racket")
      (lib-dir . "/usr/lib/racket")
      (share-dir . "/usr/share/racket")
      (include-dir . "/usr/include/racket")
      (bin-dir . "/usr/bin")
      (apps-dir . "/usr/share/applications")
      (man-dir . "/usr/share/man")
      (absolute-installation? . #t)
      (catalogs . ("https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.7/catalog/" #f))
      (build-stamp . "")
      (doc-search-url . "https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.7/doc/local-redirect/index.html")
;;lib-search-dirs
      (lib-search-dirs . ("....."))
;; O si es un ddl dll-dir 
      (dll-dir . ("....."))
)
```